# Upload an image in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am uploading an image to firebase. It is uploaded correctly but the problem is in storing that URL of firebase storage to real-time database. It was working correctly in the previous version of android but now I have updated my android studio now it's not working can any one help me

`task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();` I am getting error in `getDownloadUrl`

Here is the code:

```
 imageRef.putFile(filePath).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {

                    if(task.isSuccessful()){

                        final String download_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                       databaseReference.child("image").setValue(download_url).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {

                               if(task.isSuccessful())
                               {
                                   progressDialog.dismiss();
                                   Toast.makeText(Setting_activity.this, "Success Uploading.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                               }
                           }
                       });
```

Comment: what is the error ? post your logcat here also

Comment: Please let me see the full error log.

Comment: sir it is working right now coz i was using latest version of android studio and now i have the way how to upload and save the link in real time database